# How can I choose my time of visit to avoid the crowds at the Paris Catacombs?

Tags: france, paris, seasonal

This includes time of day, day of the week, month of the year, season, anything useful.

I went here once around noon on a weekday recently and it was a 90 minute line, which is crazy-- no other attraction in Paris has had any line at *all* for me so far. Since the whole line is just standing outside in the open sun, and it was 95 degreees F, I had to just leave.

When do the crowds subside?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is normal to see long crowds there ([even Google Street View shows the queue](https://www.google.it/maps/place/Catacombs+of+Paris/@48.833966,2.3322336,3a,75y,75.93h,85.57t/data=!3m7!1e1!3m5!1s89eHCj-HOcMEGXMKorgFkw!2e0!6s%2F%2Fgeo1.ggpht.com%2Fcbk%3Fpanoid%3D89eHCj-HOcMEGXMKorgFkw%26output%3Dthumbnail%26cb_client%3Dmaps_sv.tactile.gps%26thumb%3D2%26w%3D203%26h%3D100%26yaw%3D166.2531%26pitch%3D0!7i13312!8i6656!4m5!3m4!1s0x0:0xc8d7f073e62eb4b3!8m2!3d48.8338325!4d2.3324222!6m1!1e1)), but [google](https://www.google.com/search?q=paris%20catacombs&oq=paris%20catacombs) suggests it is less busy Wednesday to Friday, either around opening time (ideally get there sometime before 10 a.m. or in the late evening, around 6 p.m. maybe, [last entrance time is 7:30 p.m.](http://www.catacombes.paris.fr/en/visit/access-opening-times-accessibility/access-and-timetables))

[image]

Even better, [the catacombs have their own statistics on best access time](http://www.catacombes.paris.fr/sites/catacombes/files/editeur/frequentation_du_site_des_catacombes_annee_2015.pdf) (measured as average waiting time, for 2015).

**clearly the best time to visit is**

## off-season from October to April, outside of school holidays, between Wednesday and Friday in the afternoon from 3 to 7 p.m.

**in summer you are basically always in for a long wait, so come prepared**, e.g. with an umbrella for shade, water and good company or something to keep you busy during your 90+ minute wait.

[image]